# Using Chef Solo to provision a Windows EC2 instance and bootstrap it

Tags: windows, amazon-ec2, provisioning, chef-infra, chef-solo

I'm trying to automate our CI process for a couple of .NET apps, and in a perfect world I'd like to spin up a Windows EC2 instance for each, bootstrap the instance to install Chef Solo and then execute a Chef recipe to install some dependencies and the packaged software itself.

However - I'm a novice and have no idea even if that is feasible let alone where to start :)

I'm fairly well versed with the command line tools for AWS so can spin up an AMI ok, but beyond that point I'm pretty stuck. I would like to avoid building a custom AMI with chef pre-installed as that takes a lot of the advantages away.

I think this is essentially what I need to do - but is (unsurprisingly) focused on Linux:

http://www.opinionatedprogrammer.com/2011/06/chef-solo-tutorial-managing-a-single-server-with-chef/

Does anyone have a link to someone who has done this or similar before? Or a better way of achieving what I'd like to do?

Any help appreciated.

Comment: What advantages do you feel you lose when building a custom AMI?

Comment: Seperation between the OS and the application packaging itself. As I understand it AMIs are generally meant to be "clean" OS installs (with latest patches) on top of which you deploy your dependencies and applications.

Comment: Plus - building an new AMI is not exactly lightweight, and I'd be creating new deployment packages at least nightly for Chef to install.

Comment: Maybe you want to take a look at https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant-aws/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, this requires that you have Chef preinstalled on your AMI:

http://scottwb.com/blog/2012/12/13/provision-and-bootstrap-windows-ec2-instances-with-chef/

But *this* is a strategy for installing Puppet to a stock Windows AMI, which could easily be modified for Chef:

http://dansrandombits.blogspot.com/2012/06/bootstrapping-custom-windows-ec2.html

I can't say I've done this yet, but I've both in my bookmarks bar since they was posted and have been planning on giving it a shot in at least our dev environment at some point. It seems like as long as there's a solid silent install for Chef, you could pull this off.

Answer (score 0):

I realize this post is a bit old, but for those that still may come across this.  I'm provisioning servers using Chef-Solo.  Essentially I configure the User-Data of the instance to download and install Chef, download the cookbooks/recipes, and then launch Chef-Solo.

Here's a blog post I've made to demonstrate the steps:  http://thesysadminswatercooler.blogspot.com/2015/11/aws-bootstrap-windows-ec2-instance-with.html